# SourceTree - Added files not recognized in filesystem windows

Tags: git, sourcetree

Regards,

I have realized commit, push, see all the files, press "Add/Remove" and nothing yet.

I closed and started SourceTree several times, administrator, refreshed and single mode files *.js , but not with these images:

[image: Filesystem]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, well! It's ok... Experience with git: Pattern ignored in .gitgnore. I refreshed and works!.

You can also check: Ignored from "Pending files" list from SourceTree.

**See exclusion below:**

[image: .gitinore]

Thanks!.